# Programatically determine if a given VOB is mounted in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

I am trying to programatically determine if a VOB is mounted in clearcase.
Specifically, I want to run a command and parse the output.

However, I can't seem to find this information in `cleartool describe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cleartool lsvob \theVob
```

should be enough

If there is a star (`*`): it is mounted

```
* \thevob
```

If there is not: it is not yet mounted.

See [command lsvob](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsvob.htm).

:_

By default, `lsvob` lists all VOBs registered in the current network region, whether or not they are mounted (active).
The default output line can include up to six fields, as shown in this example:

```
* /vobs/src /net/host2/usr/vobstore/src_vob public (ucmvob, replicated)
```

> The output fields report:
>
> - **Whether the VOB is mounted (*)**
> - The VOB tag
> - The VOB storage directory path name
> - Whether the VOB is public or private (see the [`mkvob` reference page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkvob.htm))
> - Whether the VOB is a UCM project VOB (`ucmvob`)
> - Whether the VOB is replicated (`replicated`)

Comment: Oof, you even get the easy ones. How's a guy meant to get any points round here :S

Answer (score 2):

I've found if you have a view already running, a simple "if exists" \view\\VOB works. Sometimes (if for example you're trying to use the CAL, things can be a tad slow at times)

I.E.

Perl

```
if (-d "\\view\onaclov\TESTVOB")
{
    #do something now
}
```

Batch

```
if not exists \\view\onaclov\TESTVOB <insert mount command here>
```

The above will check for a particular folder, if it doesn't exist, you can do a mount vob command.

VB.NET

```
If System.Io.Directory.Exists("\\view\onaclov\TESTVOB") then
    'Blah
end if
```

Just some additional insight. (you don't always have to use the Clearcase/Quest tools to do what you need)