# 'cleartool find -print' inside Python3 'subprocess.check_output' returns empty string

Tags: python, subprocess, clearcase

I am trying to run the following command using Python subprocess

```
/usr/atria/bin/cleartool find <path> -follow -name '*.elf' -version "lbtype(CXC1111-111)" -print
```

Code snippet:

```
cmd = [clt, 'find', path, '-follow', '-name', '\"*.elf\"', '-version', lb, "-print"]
try:         
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)

    print("--%s--" % output)
    print("===DONE===")
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print("CALLEDPROCESSERROR")
    print(e)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as e:
    print(e)
```

o/p after running the snippet

```
--b''--

===DONE===
```

When the `cleartool find` command is executed on shell, the filename is printed

Ideally in python script output should print the filename.
Any ideas where this is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `subprocess.Popen` has `shell=False`.  The `check_output` function passes its arguments along to `Popen`, so you're getting `shell=False` here too.  Without invoking the shell, each argument is passed uninterpreted to `cleartool`.  When you run, from the shell, the command:

```
cleartool find ... -name '*.elf' -version "lbtype(CXC1111-111)" ...
```

(bits snipped to make this fit better in the window), the single and double quotes are stripped by the shell, so that `cleartool` just gets `*.elf` and `lbtype(CXC1111-111)`.  Those are the byte-sequences you need to pass with `shell=False`.  (Keeping `shell=False` is probably best; if you set it to `True` you'll have to paste the command up into a single string and quote shell metacharacters.)

Comment: Good catch, more specific than my own answer below. So +1.

Comment: Your explanation on cleartool and shell makes me clear. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think i figured out the problem.

Before solution, here is how my lb and cmd looks

```
lb = '\"lbtype(%s-%s)\"' % (tmp_prod_no, rev)
cmd = [clt, 'find', lm_path, '-follow', '-name', '\"*.elf\"', '-version', lb, "-print"]
```

\" tags are the culprit for the problem
After following modifications (lb and *.elf), it works fine

```
lb = 'lbtype(%s-%s)' % (tmp_prod_no, rev)
cmd = [clt, 'find', lm_path, '-follow', '-name', '*.elf', '-version', lb, "-print"]
```

Can some one explain how subprocess deal with quotes in command.
Here are different combinations i tried and the errors

Case 1 - Double quotes for lb and elf

```
lb = '\"lbtype(%s-%s)\"' % (tmp_prod_no, rev)
cmd = [clt, 'find', lm_path, '-follow', '-name', '\"*.elf\"', '-version', lb, "-print"]

o/p:
--b''--
===DONE===
```

Case 2 - Double quotes for elf

```
lb = 'lbtype(%s-%s)' % (tmp_prod_no, rev)
cmd = [clt, 'find', lm_path, '-follow', '-name', '\"*.elf\"', '-version', lb, "-print"]    

o/p:
cleartool: Error: Syntax error in query (near character 1).
cleartool: Error: Invalid query: ""lbtype(CXC1727075-R78A12)""
cleartool: Warning: Skipping   \vobs/cello/babs/control_test_dm/jpre_test_lm/bin/jpre_test.ppc.elf".
CALLEDPROCESSERROR
Command '['/usr/atria/bin/cleartool', 'find',   '/vobs/cello/babs/control_test_dm/jpre_test_lm', '-follow', '-name', '*.elf', '-version', '"lbtype(CXC1727075-R78A12)"', '-print']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Case 3 - No Double quotes gives correct answer

```
lb = 'lbtype(%s-%s)' % (tmp_prod_no, rev)
cmd = [clt, 'find', lm_path, '-follow', '-name', '*.elf', '-version', lb, "-print"]

o/p:
--b'\vobs\asd\asd\adasd'--
===DONE===
```

Why the clearcase complaining about lbtype in Case 2 but not in Case 1.

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in "[`cleartool find`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17435684/6309)" prerequisite, a `find` must be executed from within a ClearCase view (snapshot or dynamic);

You need to make sure the Python subprocess:

- keep the current path
- has the vob mounted in that process (if you are using a dynamic view).

[torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572226/cleartool-find-print-inside-python3-subprocess-check-output-returns-empty-s/17573127?noredirect=1#comment25594657_17573127) a simpler cause for the issue:

> **The default for the various subprocess invocations is `shell=False`**

See [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17588474/6309).

---

That is especially true if your path (on the shell) is /vobs: that is only valid for a view which has been set, which spawns its own process. See "[Python and ClearCase setview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309)" for more.
It wouldn't allow an alias like '`clt`' to work either ('`cleartool`' might work, '`clt`' not: see "[Clearcase running commands from a script (error: Bad phone number)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10416258/6309)" as an example)

Try it in a dynamic view using the full path of said dynamic view:

```
/view/aView/vobs/aVob/...
```

A good test would be for your Python script to do first:

- a print of the `cwd` (current working directory)
- a `cleartool lsvob` (to see, if you are within a dynamic view, if [those vobs are still mounted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1121417/6309) in the python subprocess).

Comment: I replaced cmd with the below line and i got the correct output         cmd = [clt, "ls", vobfile]                                           So i believe settings related to vlearcase view should be fine.

Comment: @Hemanth or `cleartool find` somehow prints on stderr instead of stdout?

Comment: You are right (of course) about all the cleartool restrictions, but the problem in this case is much simpler. :-)  The default for the various `subprocess` invocations is `shell=False`.

Comment: BTW in previous $orkplace I had a side project of attempting to write something like cvsps for ClearCase.  I found a lot of your info on CC here on SO really useful.  (Side project never got that far, and it's now "previous $orkplace".  But still, tracking down original checkins from multisite zippy merges, ugh.)

Comment: @torek Thank you. Funnily enough, I was in charge to write a ClearCase to Git import tool. That workspace is also referred as "previous" ;)